# How to solve an equation given certain parameters?

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

I am new to *Mathematica* so please bear with me. I have an equation that has around 7 parameters and one unknown. I was able to use `FindRoot` to solve it; however, I want to do the same for around 1000 rows of parameters. I usually do this in Excel were I just drag down the same command for all rows to get the result for each row. I tried to use the `Table`, `Matrix`, and other commands but couldn't understand how it works. I think there is something wrong with my understanding on how *Mathematica* works. Any suggestions on guiding me is greatly appreciated.

Edit#1

For example,

`a     b     c     f(x)=ax^2+bx+c       Findroot f(x)`

`2     3     3     f(x)=2x^2+3x+3            ?`

`2     2     1     f(x)=2x^2+2x+1            ?`

`5     3     5     f(x)=5x^2+3x+5            ?`

`.     .     .            .                  .`

`.     .     .            .                  .`

`.     .     .            .                  .`

`2     8     3     f(x)=2x^2+8x+3            ?`

Edit#2

I tried the following as suggested by @belisarius ;however, i get "
FindRoot::nveq: The number of equations does not match the number of variables in "

`params = {{{61.07213, 118.844, 127.4626, 133.3232, 140.4969, 154.6745,
      0.0725203, 0.0459785, 0.0538076, 0.1009101, 
     0.1382398, -0.0140873}, {349.7488, 115.493, 114.1906, 112.2911, 
     110.223, 108.051, 0.1205766, 0.1778708, 0.1969301, 0.2107067, 
     0.2875397, -0.0140873}, {579.7379, 332.051, 383.5087, 437.5052, 
     493.8236, 556.8684, 0.2324231, 0.2111662, 0.1930639, 0.1914745, 
     0.2012774, -0.0140873}}};`

`f[{m_, b0_, b1_, b2_, b3_, b4_, roe1_, roe2_, roe3_, roe4_, roe5_, 
   gCT_}] := 
 FindRoot[b0 + (b0 (-R + roe1))/(1 + R) + (
   b1 (-R + roe2))/(1 + R)^2 + (b2 (-R + roe3))/(1 + R)^3 + (
   b3 (-R + roe4))/(1 + R)^4 + (
   b4 (-R + roe5))/(1 + 
     R)^5 + ((1 + gCT) b4 (-R + roe5))/((1 + R)^5 (-gCT + R)) - m, {R,
    0}]`

`f /@ params`

Any ideas on why I get this result?

Comment: "...bare with me."? Do I really need to get naked? ;-} And what you're after will be in the *Map* and *Apply* families. See the docs. for more info.

Comment: It might not seem like it, but for a new user you may have picked a problem that is a little too difficult. Imagine being new to Excel. How much would you have needed to learn to do this problem? Now study this example: params = {{a, b, c}, {2, 3, 3}, {2, 2, 1}}; f[{p1_, p2_, p3_}] := x /. Solve[p1*x^2 + p2*x + p3 == 0, x]; Map[f, params]  Look up each of those functions in the help system and read until you understand it. There is a lot to learn to be able to do something like this.

Comment: @Bill Impressive, isn't it? That's why many people abandon Mma: the learning curve

Comment: @Bill Thank you very much, that really help me.

Comment: In your edited example you have triple curly braces in `param`. You should have only two levels

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 4):

```
(*First we defime our "rows"*)
params = {{2, 3, 3}, {2, 2, 1}, {5, 3, 5}};

(*Now we define a function of the params that solves the equation*)
f[{a_, b_, c_}] := Solve[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x]

(*and we apply the function to each parameter set at a time*)
f /@ params // Column
(*
{{{x -> 1/4 (-3 - I Sqrt[15])}, {x -> 1/4 (-3 + I Sqrt[15])}},
 {{x -> -(1/2) - I/2}, {x -> -(1/2) + I/2}},
 {{x -> 1/10 (-3 - I Sqrt[91])}, {x -> 1/10 (-3 + I Sqrt[91])}}}
*)
```